# Is it possible to extract coordinate information from neato or GraphViz?

Tags: matlab, graph, graphviz, neato

Once I have generated a graph with neato, is it possible to extract the coordinate information of the vertices that neato has calculated?

I would like to use this information to plot a graph in MATLAB; I can't use gplot without any coordinate information, and all I have is the adjacency matrix.

Currently I am using MATLAB to plot a biograph, then extracting the coordinate information from that biograph to use with gplot, however the biograph drawing function runs a lot slower than neato, and the quality of graph layout is a lot better with neato as well.

Does anyone have any ideas that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphviz offers a variety of [output formats](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html), among them [`dot`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:dot) and `xdot`.

The `dot` output format contains layout information for the graph and its nodes and edges. If that's not enough, `xdot` provides even more detailed information about how graphviz would draw the graph.

You may call neato with one of those output formats (`-Tdot` parameter) and you then may parse the output. Or you may use the `gvpr` tool (graphviz pattern scanning and processing language) to format the output in a custom and easily parseable manner (see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28100124/63733)).

See also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8389209/63733) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837414/63733) for example xdot output.